# Import a large sql file (30 gb per day) to one single index in elasticseach

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have sql dump (40 GB) generated every day, i would like to migrate this dump to elasticseach in one single index ex: the dump of yesterday was transferred to index1, the dump of today should be transferred to the same index (i.e index1), and the next dumps over next days should also be appended the same index (index1).

My question: in elasticsearch, how can structure the index to store these large dumps generated every day?

Comment: Is that always new data or mostly an update of existing data? So the total size of the dataset will keep growing or stay more or less the same over time?

Comment: it is a new data and it keep growing over the days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem is with your usage pattern that each shard should have a certain size (depending a bit on the use case around 10 to 50GB each). With one index this would be very hard to achieve.

What you want is called a [rollover index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/indices-rollover-index.html), which basically creates a new index after hitting a certain condition — this would probably be size for you. And having an alias pointing to all the indices you can easily search across the entire dataset.

Also the recent feature [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/index-lifecycle-management.html) makes the management of rollover indices much simpler, so this is what I'd look into here.

Comment: Thank you xeraa!. what if the answer to your question is  "mostly an update of existing data" ?

Comment: That's fine. It will replace existing documents as needed and create a new index when the data size grows.

Comment: xeraa, please could you tell me how many primary shard per index  should i use? and how could i know that: 1. one primary shard is full? 2. the index s full? thank you.

Comment: A shard isn‘t full, but there‘s a sweetspot for performance, overhead, and recovery. For your use case I‘d go with something like 10 to 20GB of data per primary shard. Configure the rollover policy and you‘re good to go.

Comment: in fact i am using logstash for transferring. What about the heap size for both elasticsearch and logstash? and the cpu and ram for the server? how many size should they be?

Comment: There's no simple answer for that — it depends on many factors: How complex is your Logstash pipeline, is the data one big batch or spread out over the day, how complex are your mappings and queries, how frequent are your queries, what is the total data size (today will be much less than in 90 days based on your description),... Start with something and see how it develops. Also a cloud service might make a lot of sense for your growing use case.

Comment: Xeraa, 
1). I confirm that the data is one big batch (generated every day at 7:00 pm).

Comment: 2). My logstash output section looks like the following :  output {
   elasticsearch {
  index => "index-000001" 
    document_id => "%{id_ot}"
  hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"  
  user => elastic
  password => changeme
 }.
  
  My indices follows this pattern (index-\*),
  My question is : which index should i make in index key word? i.e, is  index => "index-000001"  correct ?
   << since if the index-000001 is full, the next index (index-000002) will generated>>, Or should 
   i make index => "index-\*", or something else ?

Comment: No, ILM should manage one writable alias and this is the one you target with Logstash. But this is a totally different question now than the initial one and should go into its own thread. The comments are not the place to resolve that.

Comment: Xeraa, in your response you said "And having an **alias pointing to all the indices** you can easily search across the entire dataset". Could you tel me how to do that?

Comment: You need to set the [`is_write_index` attribute in the alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#aliases-write-index)